# Ruby on rails: Using Refile Gem, displaying the images without cropping or distorting images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-4, refile

I'm able to upload multiple images, but I'm not sure how to customize the size of the image.

This is how I view the images:

```
<%= attachment_image_tag(image, :file, :fill, 300, 300) %>
```

`:fill` : crops the images

`300, 300` : is the height and width

Before refile, I had hardcoded the source of the images, and then I used this CSS to fix the size of the image.

```
img {
  display:block;
  max-height: 430px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
```

I wanted to have a height consistent throughout, but the width can be any size and won't be distorted or cropped.

At the time of this post, I was thinking that I can get away with increasing the width and height in the refile attachment_image_tag option to like `800, 800`, but it still crops the images... Also, I tried to get rid of `:fill`, but my images won't show, and the code just breaks.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at Refile wiki you will find that there are other methods to crop the image : [see here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/refile/Refile/ImageProcessor)

As I can see in your css you were looking for a max-height of 430px but if the image height is lower than 430px you would not expand it to be exactly 430px so I think it's not logical to use `fill`, instead I would use `limit`

```
<%= attachment_image_tag(image, :file, :limit, 300, 300) %>
```

as the documentation says :

**limit(img, width, height)** :

> Resize the image to fit within the specified dimensions while
>   retaining the original aspect ratio. Will only resize the image if it
>   is larger than the specified dimensions. The resulting image may be
>   shorter or narrower than specified in either dimension but will not be
>   larger than the specified values.

In your case you are looking just to fix the height and you would like the width to be any size right ? so after looking at the code of [limit](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/refile/Refile%2FImageProcessor%3Alimit) it looks like this :

```
def limit(img, width, height)
  img.resize "#{width}x#{height}>"
end
```

Refile use *Imagemagick* to crop the image and If I am not wrong you can achieve that doing something like this :

```
x430          # width = any size, height = 430
```

So I think you can just set the width param of `limit` to **nil** like that :

```
<%= attachment_image_tag(image, :file, :limit, nil, 430) %>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This did help me. I didn't know where to look for the other methods. I used `:fit` instead of `:limit`, however, you would need to add a width. I'm just not sure how you can do 100%? I will accept this answer, but it guided me to the right place, but if I can do 100% in the width, how would I do so?

Comment: does this not working for you :  attachment_image_tag(image, :file, :limit, , 430)

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...image_tag(image, :file, :fit, , 430) );`

Comment: what about trying this : attachment_image_tag(image, :file, :limit, nil , 430)

Comment: @hellomello it worked with nil ? let me know so I can edit my answer

Comment: Wait! i'm so sorry, I'm an idiot... I don't think it worked. I accidentally had 800, nil, 430. So I added an extra variable between the width and height, but somehow it generated images still. However, when I deleted a few things within my view, and just made it bare and minimal just to see the code, it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83817/discussion-between-medbo-and-hellomello).